# how to implement advanced search in rails with form validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, advanced-search

I have a problem with this scenario in ruby on rails 4, hope you guys can help me out.

I have **products**, **brands**, **prices** and **users** tables:

- **products**: name, description,user_id,...
- **brands**: title
- **prices**: value, shipping_fee,...
- **users**: username, password,...

I need a search page that allows people search products based on:

- prices (minimum, maximum)
- brands
- seller name (it would be a join to users table)

What's your suggestion for the best way implementing such scenario? (or I should say cleanest way)

ps1: **I need to validate fields in the search form.**

ps2: I've seen sunspot and I don't think if that kind of full-text search be a good option for my scenario

Comment: Could you show some of your code that you have written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) gem.

It allows you implement a search in controller using the resource scopes.